# Bootstrap: Collapse fixed top navigation menu to slide-in from left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, off-canvas-menu

I would like to change the default behavior of bootstrap top fixed navigation from push-in from top to slide-in from left. I have seen a lot of people using off-canvas but they are using it with sidebar navigation. I have failed to find any working example on implementation of top fixed navigation into slide-in from left in collapsed state.

I would appreciate if you someone could shed some light on this on how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link , it will guide you with what you want. This has various out of the box  off-canvas implementations (slide-in, push, reveal): http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas

Comment: i have tried reading it. Haven't really figured out how to use it with main top navigation. All examples convert a sidebar into off canvas. Nothing converts too fixed into off canvas